# Sentido do "pêlo na venta"?

Tags: significado, português-europeu, expressões-idiomáticas

Não entendo a lógica da expressão **"pêlo na venta"**?

> [**Venta**](https://dicionario.priberam.org/venta)
>
> *nome feminino*
>
> 1. Cada uma das fossas nasais. = NARINA
>
> **Ventas**
>
> *nome feminino plural*
>
> 2. [Informal]  Nariz.
> 3. [Informal]  Cara.
> 4. [Informal]  Presença (ex.: o roubo deu-se nas ventas da polícia).
>
> **ventar**
>
> *verbo transitivo*
>
> 1. Haver vento, soprar com força o vento.
> 2. [Figurado]  Ser propício, favorável.
> 3. [Informal]  Soltar ventosidades.
> 4. Surgir ou mostrar-se de repente.

Já se formos ver a palavra pêlo, encontramos:

> [**pê·lo**](https://dicionario.priberam.org/pelo)
>
> *nome masculino*
>
> (...)
>
> **pêlo na venta**
>
> - [Informal]  Mau génio (ex.: a avó tinha pêlo na venta, fervia em pouca água e ralhava muito).
> - [Informal]  Ousadia, valentia (ex.: são precisos mais homens e mulheres com pêlo na venta).

Isto leva-me a pensar que o sentido dado no dicionário a *"pêlo na venta"* está mais relacionado com o verbo **ventar** do que outra coisa.

Answer (score 2):

Penso que "venta" é aqui "rosto" ou "narina" mesmo.

Pelo facial é tido como uma característica masculina e portanto mulheres com pelos faciais notáveis por vezes são consideradas mais masculinas, atribuindo-se a elas características como agressividade, assertividade, etc., como exemplificado em expressões como a da pergunta ("pêlo na venta") ou ditados como "Mulher com bigode nem o diabo pode".